# How to add a new line/linebreak in php code

Tags: php

i am wondering if someone can help me. I know html more than php.

I need to put a line break after each part of the address string here.

```
<?php echo $this->get_detail($order, 'address_1');?>
<?php
$address2 = $this->get_detail($order, 'address_2');
$country = $this->get_detail($order, 'country');
if (!empty($address2)) echo ", ".$this->get_detail($order, 'address_2');
?>
, <?php echo $this->get_detail($order, 'city');?>, <?php echo $this- 
>get_detail($order, 'state');?>, <?php echo $this->get_detail($order, 
'postcode'); ?> <?php
if ($country) echo ", ".$country;   
?>
```

So new line after address1, new line after address 2 etc How can i do this? I have read about \n but don't know where to put it.

Also i want to put a line space above and below the title "customer note:" that this produces

```
$customer_note = is_callable(array($order, 'get_customer_note')) ? $order- 
>get_customer_note() : $order->customer_note;
if ($customer_note) {
echo __('Customer Note:', 'woocommerce').' '.$customer_note."\n";
}
```

Again i am not sure how to best do this. Any help would be very very welcome.

**So what both codes above produce at the moment is:**

House number and street, town, county, postcode , country
Customer Note: this is the customer note blah blah blah.....

**What i want it to look like is this:**

House number and street
town
county
postcode
country

Customer Note: 

this is the customer note blah blah blah.....

Comment: use `<br>`'s instead of `\n`. The latter is for writing to files. If you look at your HTML source right now, you'll see they're there alright.

Comment: This code is from a .php file. I tried adding <br> but didn't work.

Comment: You need to show what _didn't work_.

Comment: take it up with the answers below then.

Answer (score 4):

`\n` is a line break.

---

use of `\n` with

### **1. echo directly to page**

Now if you are trying to echo string to the page:

```
echo  "kings \n garden";
```

***output*** will be:

```
kings garden
```

you won't get `garden` in new line because PHP is a server-side language, and you are sending output as HTML, you need to  create line breaks in HTML. HTML doesn't understand `\n`. You need to use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function for that.

What it does is:

> Returns string with `<br />` or `<br>` inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

```
echo  nl2br ("kings \n garden");
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vc7HJB)

```
kings
garden
```

> **Note** Make sure you're echoing/printing `\n` in double quotes, else it will be rendered literally as \n. because php interpreter parse string in single quote with concept of ***as is***

```
so "\n" not '\n'
```

### **2. write to text file**

Now if you echo to text file you can use just `\n` and it will echo to a new line, like:

```
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w+")  ;

$txt = "kings \n garden";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

output will be:

```
kings
 garden
```

Comment: About your */n is not* - Where'd that come from? I didn't see that in the OP. Some magic rabbit working behind the scenes here?

Comment: This was a 2-part question btw.

Comment: Sorry. I just tried to share as much as I knew. I'll keep those things in mind next time. Thanks for your advice @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 1):

Newlines in HTML are expressed through `<br>`, not through \n.
example:

```
<?php
  echo"Fo\n";
  echo"Pro";
?>
```

**output**

```
Fo
Pro
```

**or you can use this:**

```
<?php
  echo"Fo";
  echo"<br>";/* this print new line*/
  echo "pro";
?>
```